# Register Font for Multiple .AS Files

Tags: actionscript, fonts

I'm embedding a few fonts in my ActionScript file as follows:

```
[Embed(source="DAXCOMPL.TTF", fontName="DaxCompact-Light", mimeType='application/x-font', embedAsCFF='false')]
private var MyFont:Class;
```

This is done in the main `Canvas` that is placed by the mxml. This canvas creates several smaller canvases and places them as children. I have each of these sub-canvases split up into a separate .as file for ease of use. The problem I'm running into is that I would like to use this font in these .as files without having to pass it around. Is it possible to somehow register the font globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set it as a public static const in its own file. I do this if I need to embed a bunch of icons as well. Makes it easy to say `Icons.ADD` or something lie that.

```
package your.project.someplace
{
    public final class MyFonts{
         [Embed(source="DAXCOMPL.TTF", fontName="DaxCompact-Light",mimeType='application/x-font', embedAsCFF='false')]
         public static const DAXCOMPL:Class;

    }
}
```

Now anytime you need to use it, call the static class.

```
MyFonts.DAXCOMPL;
```

Comment: It seemed easier to do the fonts in the MXML, but I think this solution better actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I had assumed you were using FLASH... but it looks like your using MXML (Flex) in which case you can just set a style in a stylesheet.

```
@font-face
{
src:                url("DAXCOMPL.TTF");
fontFamily:             DaxCompact;
}
```

Then in your main app file you can say `<mx:Style source="myCSSFile.css"/>`